# I can't draw a horizontal line on grid in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How do I draw a horizontal line on a grid? See the picture
[image]
As you see, the black line is a bit higher than the grid line. When I move the black line a bit lower, it overshoots the grid.
All my settings are default.
The problem happens on every second line of a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is actually a shape, not a connector. Use the line from General instead

[image: The general library section of draw.io opened with the line connector hovered over]